# How to Confg EntityFramework to work with multiple Databases C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, entity-framework-6

> I'm trying to create a program that depends on Entity Framework but i
>   need to create two types of databases Sql and Sqlite with the same DB
>   schema in order to change to sql server if the program will work on
>   different PCs

trying this Sol but DeDefaultConnectionFactory has been Deprecated 
https://github.com/narendrasinghrathore/entityMultipleDb

I don't want to create many DbContext class just one and changing the provider and the connection string.

Anybody have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass the connection string name in the constructor of the `DbContext` class

```
// make your connectionString variable dynamic based on your connection type
if(connType == "SQL")
  context = new DbContext(sQLConnectionString);
else
  context = new DbContext(sQLLiteConnectionString);
```

For more info - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.

Comment: can you tell me how i can use it with my model that inherits DbContext, please note that the changing between two db types will perform at runtime

Comment: You can simply pass the dynamic connection string to your context class like this 

`public MyContext()
            : base(connectionString)`

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException' occurred in Test.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode. To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity Framework connection string is specified in the config file of executing application.

Comment: Are you using code first approach in your application?

Comment: No Database First this exception thrown as you see

Comment: Are you sure that you have provided the mentioned connection string in your config file

Comment: yes, the default connection string mentioned in the app config file